Reacting to a user verifying their email in a Cognito User Pool
So quick question, is there a straight-forward programmatic way to trigger some code whenever a user verifies their new email address? I know the custom email sender lambda has a trigger source for the initial part (UpdateUserAttributes), but I'd want to hook into the verification part as well. From my research, the only way to do it is to enable management events in a CloudTrail trail and then add an EventBridge rule with a lambda target, which seems overkill since there's no way to filter for specific events, and I feel like all in all costs would end up being disproportionate.
For a bit more context, I'm trying to update the database email of a user whenever their identity provider one changes, which seems like a pretty normal use case which is why it seems surprising that there isn't an apparent solution for this.

If you want to verify that the user has a verified email while authenticating, you will also get help from the Pre Token Generation Lambda. This trigger is invoked every time a token is rs generated, you could use this to check if email verifcation was successfull and it made its way into the flag that the user has been verified after last login.
In Lambda function:

Verify that the email_verified key is true

2, Take this status and compare it to the last status you have stored in your own database.
If it is a newly verified email, perform an update to the user email in your database.
